# HTML table <td> results all returning on one row

Tags: php, html

I'm currently looping SQL results from an Oracle table. All the rows from the table are returning fine, however they are all staying within on  element instead of onto a new row like below

[image]

This is my current table...

```
   <div id="smtTable" class="targetDiv">
     <table width="40%" style="margin: 0 auto; border:1px solid;text-align:center; width: auto;" class="table table-sm table-dark">
         <tr>
           <th scope="col">Area</th>
           <th scope="col">Week 18</th>
           <th scope="col">Week 19</th>
           <th scope="col">Week 20</th>
           <th scope="col">Week 21</th>
           <th scope="col">Week 22</th>
         </tr>
<?php
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
     foreach ($row as $item) {
         echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You will need to add the row tags for each row of data.  Just add the `<tr>` (and closing tags) to the `while` loop.

Comment: dont you need <tr> element for new row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close `table` and add `tr` as it's tag for rows:

```
<?php
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

echo '<tr>';
      foreach ($row as $item) {
     echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
      }
echo '</tr>';
 }
echo '</table>';
 ?>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397526/2943403 Please close close-able questions.

Comment: Your chosen answers don't explain current issue. Sometimes newbie needs to know what's wrong definitely in his case

Comment: Or they just need to be shown where the pre-existing answers are without generating needless content on Stackoverflow.